# populate an array of objectIds which belongs to nested object of another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to pick specific element from nested array of objects in dimension collection. On the other hand I've got a list of ObjectIds in products table. The collections looks like below.

**Dimension Collection:**
[image]

**Products Collection:** (how I've Dimension list in products)
[image]

Now I need that specific dimension by a product Id. I was using the below query to get the data.

```
db.dimensions.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "products",
            localField: "dimension._id",
            foreignField: "productTags",
            as: "dimensions",
        },
    },
    {
        $match: {
            dimensions: {
                $ne: [],
            },
        },
    },
    {
        $set: {
            productTags: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$dimensions",
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: {
                        $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this.productTags"],
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
    {
        $set: {
            dimension: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$dimension",
                    cond: {
                        $in: ["$$this._id", "$productTags"],
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$dimension",
    },
    {
        $replaceWith: "$dimension",
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            dimensionChild: 1,
            dimensionChildSlug: 1,
        },
    },
])
```

but this collection is returning me all the dimensions instead of a specific one. The output looks something like this.
[image]

Schemas can be found here: https://gist.github.com/SohamRoyNoel/37592d3903b60421337dda9a7a2ad4fa

Can anyone please help me with this query. Thanks in advance.